# Effect of Positive and Negative voltage supply in LM741 opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-measurement, proteus

At first,i created a simple schematic of non-inverting amplifier using LM741 having a gain of 2. The supplied a.c voltage at non-inverting input is 1V having frequency of 50 Hz. And i get the result what i had expected, the output voltage of 2 v peak and 50 Hz.

In the second scenario, i kept all the parameter same expect i grounded the negative voltage supply and i get unexpected result. Peak voltage at the output is 800 mv and lower voltage is -200mv. And the screenshot of the simulated waveform is presented below.

Tx in advance. [image: Amplifier Circuit using LM741]

Comment: *"... and i get unexpected result ..."* - it might help if you describe what result you expected, and why.

Comment: I was expecting the same sinusoidal result as before. That's what i meant by unexpected result. Tx.

Comment: LM741 is not a rail to rail op-amp. Check your input voltages against the supply.

Comment: I came across this curiosity while trying to get the concept of difference amplifier. Ok i will test it after i get the concept of rail to rail op-amp. One more question, can u help me to understand how the d.c voltage that is named as R4(2) in the figure (difference amplifier)acts as the offset voltage. the link for it is provided below; http://s33.postimg.org/km59pi2sv/test.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input voltage swings equally positive and negative then it would be expected that your output would do the same. However, with 0 volts as your most negative supply rail this cannot happen. An op-amp can only produce output voltages within the confines of its power rails.

This won't be helped by using a rail-to-rail op-amp either.

The data sheet has the full story: -

- Input voltage cannot be relied upon when closer than 3V to either rail (see input voltage range limits in DS)
- Output voltage is unreliable within 3V of either rail (see output voltage swing limits in DS)

You've broken both these rules!

Comment: I didn't get exact the line what u had written pointwise. But i got the overall story behind it. Can u plz help me out to figure the effect of the offset voltage which is labelled as R4(2) in the figure. http://s33.postimg.org/km59pi2sv/test.png Tx.

Comment: Tx Digging Sedra books and datasheets i found how the d.c voltage acts as the offset voltage and how it effects the output voltage.